# How to insert data from stored procedure into a new table using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure using PGADMIN4. Inside the SP, I have selected a view table. However, I want the data inside the stored procedure to be inserted into a new table. I have tried below code, but it is showing an error:

SP name: Test

New table name: Customer

```
Insert into public.Customer exec public.Test
```

This is my SP code:

```
create procedure test()
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
Select * from public.customer_list; 

END; 
$$;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "exec"

Comment: 1) You will need to add the code of your stored procedure to your question 2) If you are actually using a SP it does not have `RETURN` , see here [SP return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-PROCEDURE) 3) A SP needs to be used with [CALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html)

Comment: Convert your procedure to a function that returns a table. Procedures aren't meant to return result sets

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i have added my sp code

Comment: You will need a function not a procedure. For this case the simplest way is `RETURN QUERY`, see here [Returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) 43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY and look at examples. Then something like `Insert into public.Customer select * from public.test();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedures **cannot** be used in SQL. If you must have a *stored procedure* (define as code stored in the database to be executed) then change to a SQL function. Which returns a type.

```
create function copy_customer_list()
  returns setof customer_list 
  language sql
as $$
   Select * from customer_list; 
$$;
```

Then you can insert into other table with

```
insert into customer  
  select * from copy_customer_list();
```